# JQuery Passing Variable From href to load()

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass an href id to load() in JQuery, I can see from the alert the returned id# 960, so I know the id value is getting past I just don't know how to append the load url, well the $("#refreshme_"+add_id) is the important part, I use that to refresh the unique div id in the page assigned by the database pull, so it would be looking for id="refreshme_960".  My simple example that is obviously not working.  I want to refresh the db select part of the page showing the new list of cars.  Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(".add_to_favorites").livequery("click", function(event) 
    {
        var add_id = this.id.replace("add_", ""); //taken from a.href tag
        alert (id);
        $.get(this.href, function(data) 
        {
            $("#refreshme_"+add_id).load("http://www.example.com/car_list/"+add_id);
```

---

```
<a class="add_to_cars" href="/car-add/960/add'}" id="add_960">Add Car</a>
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind, but I tried putting some indendation in there to improve readability.  I couldn't make heads or tails as it was...

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?  Is it that your entire list is loading inside of the car div selected?  Or is it no loading at all?

Comment: Thanks Outlaw, yes my structure was a bit straight as an arrow, lol!

Comment: Based on an existing favorites module, that works nicely w/o JQuery, but that's so 1999.  Need to update as visitor adds cars, added cars show on their side panel always in view.  Each listing has "add to favorites?" link, when a car is added to their list, link becomes "remove from favorites?".

Answer (score 1):

You are using append() in this line

```
$('#favorite-listings').append(response);
```

Which is why you get new results added after the old ones. Change that line to

```
$('#favorite-listings').html(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit confusing, are you have 'add_to_favorites' as your trigger, and then add_to_cars in the html element.

too keep your replace id all jqueryish, i think you would use

```
$(this).attr('id', 'add_');
```

I think what you are trying to do is that when a user clicks the 'add_to_cars' link, that it adds that from an ajax response into the favorites? Though i could be wrong.

I would question why use add_960 as your id instead of just 960 (I know you aren't supposed to use numbers as id's by I do it all the time and haven't had an issue yet).

So you could do

```
$('.add_to_cars')livequery('click', function(event){
     var request=$(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
           type: GET,
           url: "http://www.example.com/car_list/"+request,
           success: function(response){
                $('.add_to_favorites').append(response)


      }
});
});
```

or something like that. again, not entirely sure what you are trying to do.